# npm ERR! prepareGitDep on npm install

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

Getting this errors on "npm install" npm version is 6.14.4 and i am getting this error for my all react-native projects.
react-native version is 0.61.2.

any luck on this.

[image]